# Chaning Port for SSH access?

Tags: unix, ssh

Im new to SSH access and was trying to access a local machine with port 22 disabled. Hover I have different ports opened and was wondering how I could attempt to access the machine using that port.

`ssh example@10.1.1.5`

Were does the port number go?

Comment: ssh -p [port number] example@10.1.1.5

Comment: But this belongs on serverfault.com :)

Comment: I imagine it would be, assuming the server's SSH daemon is set to run on port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the -p option:

```
ssh -p1022 example@10.1.1.5
```